# How to statically verify that some C# code is functional?

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming

When writing in a functional style in C#, are there any tools to statically verify that classes are immutable and functions are pure?  I imagine it to be impossible in the general case, but a tool that's right 90% of the time would still be useful.

I can imagine some reflection that checks that all member variables are `readonly`, and that all member types (and all visible subtypes) are also immutable (recursively).  I've no idea how the check on functions would begin to operate.

Comment: Why? As much as I like FP, if you're already using a multi-paradigm language you shouldn't restrict yourself to only one paradigm for the hell of it. Not to mention that pure functions and immutable data structures are about as much of a guarantee for good FP-ish code as having only non-POD classes (no free functions) in C++ guarantees good OOP code.

Comment: @delnan - I wouldn't assume that the OP is doing this for the hell of it. I can see a situation where you want to write functional code in C# that has no strange side effects when that code is called from F#.

Comment: When reading code that passes around mutable objects I find it hard myself to discover where changes happen, and where they don't.  Implicit communication between pieces of code via mutation side-effects is very hard to discover.  If only as a form of documentation to future code readers I think pure/immutable annotations can be extremely helpful, as then the reader can restrict their search for mutations and side effects to the non-FP pieces of code rather than the entire codebase.

Answer (score 1):

[Immutable] and [Pure] annotations seem to be geared towards this. Take a look at Design by Contract tools for .NET 4.0. IIRC, static verification only works with VS Ultimate, though.

Comment: Are you referring to Microsoft Code Contracts? (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/)

Comment: Correct. Edited to clarify. They rolled most of those features into C# 4.0.

Comment: Attributes are added by the developer, whom you must trust in this matter. I think the OP wants to "trust but verify".